# How to convert to timestamp into df to excel python?

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-excel

I have a dataframe like this:

```
 tanggal_tweet    datetime64[ns, UTC]
pengguna                      object
isi_tweet                     object
sentimen                      object
dtype: object
```

but when I applied with `df.to_excel` it returns an error:

```
ValueError: Excel does not support datetime with timezone
```

Based on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63238008/17202382, I did this

```
df['tanggal_tweet'] = df['tanggal_tweet'].apply(lambda a: pd.to_datetime(a).date())
```

and then:

```
df.to_excel()
```

When I look at the excel file, I look at `tanggal_tweet`, but there is no time information, just the date. My question is, how to convert the dataframe to excel without removing the time?

Comment: oh my god, thats exactly what i want, should i delete this post or you can answer it?

Comment: Let me answer for future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove timezone information with `tz_localize`:

```
df['tanggal_tweet'] = df['tanggal_tweet'].dt.tz_localize(None)
```