# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'datetime_withtimezone'

Tags: python

I don't know hoy to solve this problem, i'm trying to export in excel the information, but dictionary's date don't let me do it.

Could you help me out?

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
import numpy as np
tcker = yf.Ticker('JPY=X')
data = tcker.history(period = '1y',interval= '1d' )
data.to_excel("history.xlsx", encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Comment: Can you share the entire error message please?

Answer (score 0):

Excel does not support the dates with timezones. Workarounds are discussed here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65204876/20178809