# Load, convert JSON to excel with Pandas in Python

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have text files that contain JSON.  Using python I want to convert the JSON into an excel file via Pandas.

Here is my JSON format in the files (json_test.txt)

```
{"time_utc":"2024-01-01T22:07:48.435Z","First Name":"Joe","Last Name":"Smith","Dept":"HR"}
{"time_utc":"2024-01-01T22:07:48.435Z","First Name":"Sarah","Last Name":"Smith","Dept":"HR"}
{"time_utc":"2024-01-01T22:07:48.435Z","First Name":"Mary","Last Name":"Smith","Dept":"Finance"}
{"time_utc":"2024-01-01T22:07:48.435Z","First Name":"James","Last Name":"Smith","Dept":"Marketing"}
{"time_utc":"2024-01-01T22:07:48.435Z","First Name":"Sarah","Last Name":"Smith","Dept":"Marketing"}
```

I'm not sure what the most efficient way of doing this is.  My initial code is

```
import os
import pathlib as Path
import json
import pandas as pd

df_json = pd.DataFrame()

def main():

    with open("json_test.txt", 'r') as f:
        data_str = f.readlines()
        df_json = json.load(data_str)
        f.close()

        df_json.to_excel('json_to_excel.xlsx', index=False)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When i run this code i get a "TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, on the json.loads() statement.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you have JSON lines in your file. Use `lines=True` in [`pd.read_json`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html#pandas-read-json):

```py
df = pd.read_json("data.json", lines=True)
df.to_excel("data.xlsx", index=False)
```

Creates `data.xlsx` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  That seems to work.  I am getting an error that i suspect is on the date.  "ValueError: Excel does not support datetimes with timezones. Please ensure that datetimes are timezone unaware before writing to Excel."  Not sure how to handle that.

Comment: @DChase Maybe answer to this question helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61802080/excelwriter-valueerror-excel-does-not-support-datetime-with-timezone-when-savin